# how to check-in or check-out files to svn from a java program

Tags: eclipse, svn

I want to check-in/check-out files from/to SVN through a java program. Can you please guide me how it can be done. I am looking at SVNKit.

updated:
How does eclipse do the check-in/check-out to SVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the [SVNKit Documentation](http://svnkit.com/documentation.html), particularly the examples on [committing to a repositor](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Committing_To_A_Repository) and [receiving changes from a repository](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Updating_From_A_Repository).

Bear in mind that SVN doesn't work on a check-in or check-out model exclusively, although locks are supported.  If other clients are accessing the same repository, you will need to be able to to merge changes too.